# Dynamic forms not submitting with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, click, submit

I have forms created as such

```
    foreach($class_pool_result["data"] as $pool) {
               $html[] = "<form action='/dashboard/attend'    method='post'    class='form_attend'>";
                $html[] = "<input type='hidden' name='pool'   value='" . $Encryption->encrypt(urlencode($pool["id"])) . "' />";
                $html[] = "<input type='hidden' name='class' value='" . $Encryption->encrypt(urlencode($class["data"]["id"])) . "' />";
                $html[] = "<table>";
                    $html[] = "<tr><td width='150'>" .    $pool["plan_name"] . "</td><td><button class='attend'>Attend</button></td><td align='left'>   <span style='color:#FF3902'>" . $pool["class_count"] . "</span> <small>classe(s)    left</small></td></tr>";
                  $html[] = "</table>";
                $html[] = "</form>";
          }
```

Then in my jquery file I try to get the click event on the button which should default to submit for a form

```
$(document).on("click", "button.attend", function(e){
    alert("hey");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/file.php", { form: , method: "add" }, function() {

    }, "json");
});
```

It does not alert anything or prevent the submissions.
I have tried replacing `click` with `submit` and `button.attend` with the form class name but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Why is your click event on the document and not a button on the form?

Comment: Because it is inside a facebox popup. I tried it with the standard $(button).on("click")... but it still didnt do anything

Comment: Well, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: A Facebook popup is likely to appear in an iframe. If it does, you're not going to be able to access that directly from the parent window

Comment: Oh ya, your are right. I think they may have a $post function for it. I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

bind submit to the form.

```
$(".form_attend").on("submit", function(){
//do stuff
} );
```

and change your button to:

```
<input type="submit" value="attend"/>
```

Plus, if you're adding the form dynamically with some other code not shown, make sure you add the element's selector your adding it to ie:

```
<div id="appending-here">
<form></form>//your form
</div>
```

your selector should be:

```
 $("#appending-here").on("submit", ".form_attend", function(){//stuff})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form.myform').on('submit', function(){
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value){


        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] = value; 

    });

        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:type,
            data:data,
            success:function(output){
            $('#res').html(output).slideDown("slow");

            }

        });

    return false;

});
```

myform is the name of the class you put in the form tag.. ge